# Filter EVERY category link with my plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, categories

Im writing a plugin to let users customize the colors of their category links. But in order to make this work, Ive gotta figure out a way to target all category links regardless of theme.

So clearly I can't go after classes so I was thinking I could write a filter to het all category links. I was thinking this would work:

```
add_filter('category_link ','kjd_filter_category_links');
function kjd_filter_category_links($id){
    die();
}
```

But it doenst look like the function is ever called.  I just tried dropping that into my functions file as well but its not working there either.

Comment: is the space in `'category_link '` a typo? and fyi, the category link is just a url, it's not an anchor tag. it's used everywhere a category link is output, including the admin screens.

Comment: OH yeah, youre 100% right, there was a space in there so the filter wasnt running. And the category_link does just changes the